# group actions preserve the cup product

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be an oriented compact manifold of dimension $2k$. Suppose that a compact Lie group $G$ acts differentiably on $X$ in an orientation-preserving way. Let $B$ be the ${\mathbb R}$-bilinear form on $H^k(X; {\mathbb R})$ be given by cup product evaluated on the fundamental class of $X$, i.e. $B(x,y)=(x\cup y)[X]$. Why does the induced action of $G$ on $H^k(X; {\mathbb R})$ preserve $B$?

Apologies if this question was asked before.

Comment: Because all products are natural?

Comment: Besides naturality, we also need that $g^*[X]=[X]$ for $g \in G$, which is because $G$ acts by orientation-preserving automorphisms.

Comment: You're both right (it's natural in the setting of oriented manifolds, rather than besides naturality...)